# Cannot read property 'length' of null - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can not finish one of the easiest kata on codewars. 
Want to understand where am I wrong!

> Instructions: Sum all the numbers of the array except the highest and
>   the lowest element (the value, not the index!). (The highest/lowest
>   element is respectively only one element at each edge, even if there
>   are more than one with the same value!) If array is empty, null or
>   None, or if only 1 Element exists, return 0.

```
function sumArray(array) {
  var finalSum = 0;
  if (array != null || !array) {

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      finalSum += array[i];
    }
    if (array.length === 0 || array.length <= 1) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return finalSum - Math.max(...array) - Math.min(...array);
    }
  }
}
```

Everything seems fine and should work, but it is not passing final tests.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

I tried to add in the first if `typeof array != 'null', typeof array != 'undefined'` but it did not help...

Comment: `if (array != null || !array)` means "if the array is not null, or if it is null" basically.

Comment: Use `if(array.length)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, the return of typeof of a null will be an object. That is why your first if doesn't work. You check if its not equal to null and its true, because the return will be object. Read more here [ECMAScript null](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3).

More proof on this, pull out a console and type the following.

```
a = null
typeof array // will return "object" 
a != null // will return false, even if we attributed the value of a to null.
a !== null // will false also
a == null // will return true, so let's use this !
```

I assume that the error you are getting is when the test is sumArray(null) or sumArray(). In order to properly return 0, you have to do this.

```
function sumArray(array) {
  var finalSum = 0;
  if (array == null) 
      return 0;
  if (array != null || !array) {

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      finalSum += array[i];
    }
    if (array.length === 0 || array.length <= 1) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return finalSum - Math.max(...array) - Math.min(...array);
    }
  }
}
```

For some weird reason, using a `array == null` will return the proper return value (true if your array is null). (I haven't read much on why).

Comment: Thank you! Yes it is working:) 
Yes, I understand that the problem is when test is checking if sumArray is null or empty. I tried to add another condition in the end of whole function `else return 0`, but that was also wrong.

As I see, your solution is working because `if (array == null)` should be checked first.

Comment: Yeah because even if you add the ```else return 0``` at the end, it still enters the if, because array is an object and not null. The oddities of Javascript !

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof array !== "undefined" && typeof array !== "null" )
```

You can try this.

Comment: I have already tried this condition, but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

check like this.

```
if(array && array.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        finalSum += array[i];
    }
    if (array.length === 0 || array.length <= 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return finalSum - Math.max(...array) - Math.min(...array);
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. And i do not understand what is checked here. But thank you!

Comment: it's checking array has some truthy value and array has at least one item in it.

Comment: The problem was solved by checking  `if (array === null) return 0;`  in the beginning. 
That way code starts to check other conditions.